# Upload Image in Android using PHP Script

Tags: php, android

I made a Android app that uploads images jpeg, png, jpg, and gifs on my server my apps says uploaded complete but when i check it on my server DirectAdmin 1.657 there is no image on that folder

here's my php script from the directadmin 1.657 hosting

```
<?php
 $target_dir = "/domains/sample.com/public_html/user-images";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]); 


 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
 echo "something when wrong when uploading the file: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "Ang file " . basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "something went wrong when uploading the file";
}
}
?>
```

here's my activity from my android application (android studio)

```
public class DataseSorterForDebugOnlyPart2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String UPLODS_URL = "http://example.com/upload.php";
private EditText fileNameEditText;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.databasesortformat_2);

    fileNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.file_name);
    Button uploadButton = findViewById(R.id.upload_button);

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String fileName = "Picsart_24-01-14_22-19-59-832";
            if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
                new UploadFileAsync().execute("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Picsart/Picsart_24-01-14_22-19-59-832.png");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(DataseSorterForDebugOnlyPart2.this, "Enter file name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String fileName = params[0];
        String responseString = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(BaseUrl.UPLOAD);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            String boundary = "*****";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            // File
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            dos.writeBytes("--" + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            int bytesAvailable = fis.available();
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, 1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fis.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, 1024);
                bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "--" + lineEnd);

            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("RERE", serverResponseMessage);

            if (serverResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                responseString = "File Uploaded Successfully";
            } else {
                responseString = "File Upload Failed";
            }

            fis.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

}
```

[image: UPDATE: I FOUND OUT THAT MY HOSTING IS NOT UPLOADING MY IMAGES]

Comment: _"my apps says uploaded complete"_ - you are checking if the HTTP status code of the response was 200 OK there. But your PHP script does not send any _different_ status code, in case the upload failed.

Comment: yes it doesn't send anything i found this php script on a blogspot website and i don't have idea How php works because this is my first time using it

Comment: If you want it to respond with a different status code: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php Alternatively, you could also respond with JSON, and have a `status` or `error` property in there, that you can check on in the client-side code, instead of using the HTTP status code to determine success or failure.

Comment: Just use a '/' in your code between target_dir and filename, hope this will solve your problem $target_file = $target_dir .'/'. basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: `echo "Ang file " . basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "something went wrong when uploading the file";
}` Your Android app is not reading this echo message. So your app does not know what happened. Open an inputstream and read this echo from the stream and then check.

Comment: I change my code and its ok now but the main problem is The filepath of my image is appeared in my database with the filepath then when i click the filepath the file is not exist or not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: i figure it out the main problem

1. i contacted my webhost provider and they fix na problem on my webdomain
2. i forgot to put a folder checker if that is exist as @blackapps mentioned

Comment: upvote comments or answers if they were useful.